# how to correct PYQT4 signal into PYQT5 signal?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I opened my old project file and I dont know how to convert the SIGNAL into pyqt5 method

QObject.connect(self.enter_data_button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.activate_comment_analyzer)

QObject.connect(self.checkBox_URL, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.checkbox_url_control)

QObject.connect(self.checkBox_ProdID, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.checkbox_prodid_control)

button.connect(button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), d.close)

i dont know how to convert this code to pyqt5 method this one is from pyqt4

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `obj.signal.connect(callable)`. For instance: `self.enter_data_button.clicked.connect(self.activate_comment_analyzer)`.